# How to reindex the solr using c#?

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore8

I'm using sitecore 8.1 with solr indexing. We are trying to rename the sitecore item name and display name dynamically from code behind. I'm able to update the above changes using manual reindex in sitecore. Is there any other efficient way to reindex the solr server Programmatically using c#?

We used following line of code. Is this right method to achieve this?

*Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexCustodian.FullRebuild(IndexController.GetIndex(database), true);*

Answer (score 0):

This is right way to rebuild index from code behind. You have two ways to do this:

// To rebuild "new" search indexes, use this piece of code for every "new" index

```
IndexCustodian.FullRebuild(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("[INDEX NAME]"), true);
```

// Or to rebuild all indexes, use the following piece of code:

```
IndexCustodian.RebuildAll();
```

And you can see more at: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/rebuild_search_indexes